# Production and development CakeEmail settings

Tags: email, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm looking to set up different development and production email environments within a CakePHP application.

In the documentation in `/app/Config/email.php` it clearly states:

```
You can specify multiple configurations for production, development and testing.
```

My question is a simple one, how?

I get that you can set up many configurations in this config file i.e.

```
class EmailConfig {
    public $default = array(
        ...
    );

    public $production = array(
        ...
    );
}
```

I'm also aware that to pick the given configuration you can do something like

```
$email  = new CakeEmail('production');
```

What I'm after then, is the best way to choose the configuration depending on whether we are on a development or production server.

Comment: I use my EmailLib class that handles this internally (using Configure config settings). Might not be the cleanest approach. But it has worked for me perfectly, so far: http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/03/30/introducing-the-emaillib/

Comment: check in your AppController's beforeFilter function for debug mode..like say

if( Configure::read('debug') == 0) {
 $email  = new CakeEmail('production');
} else {
 $email  = new CakeEmail('development');
}

Comment: @ScrappyCocco, I'm a bit reluctant to load up the email configuration for every page view considering that sending an email is probably going to be a rather rare event.  It seems like an unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the check in the constructor of EmailConfig.

```
public function __construct()
```

Comment: Exactly, here is an example how you can apply/modify certain settings: https://github.com/dereuromark/setup/blob/master/Lib/BaseEmailConfig.php